# Problema con versiones android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

Tengo un problema con mi webapp debido a que estaba utilizando un terminal de pruebas con versión android 4.1.2 y ahora al hacer pruebas en un terminal con versión android 5.1.1 no me permite hacer click en un input type text que tenía creado para introducir un código.

Además de ello la función que tenía creada para mostrar un mensaje de aviso tampoco funciona. ¿Habría alguna forma de actualizar phonegap a una versión superior?¿o podría ser culpa de algún plugin que estuviera desactualizado?

Comment: Que target y minsdk tienes configurado?

Answer (score 1):

> Antes de hacer ninguno de los cambios listados abajo, te recomendaría que hicieses una copia de seguridad del directorio donde tengas tu web app con phonegap/cordova.

Si lo que quieres hacer es actualizar phonegap, desde la línea de comandos debes hacer:

```
npm update -g phonegap
```

(Puede que necesites poner `sudo` delante en terminales de Linux/Mac).

Una vez que esté actualizado phonegap, para actualizar tu web app debes ir a su directorio y actualizar la versión de la plataforma usada (en este caso android). De nuevo, desde la línea de comandos sería algo como esto:

```
cd ruta/a/tu/webapp

phonegap platform update android
```

Por último si lo que quieres es actualizar un plugin, cordova no incluye un comando de actualización de plugins directamente, lo que puedes hacer es comprobar la versión que tienes instalada, comprobar la versión online y actualizar en caso de que sean diferentes.

Es más sencillo directamente borrar el plugin y volver a instalarlo, algo que se haría así (desde el directorio de tu web app):

```
cordova plugin rm <nombre-del-plugin>
cordova plugin add <nombre-del-plugin>
```